# Add text in MS Word doc using apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have been trying to edit different types of documents using Apache POI. The script should handle both extensions `.doc` and `.docx`. I could successfully edit the `.docx` file using `XWPF` api and the required text was added at the end of the docx file.

For editing `.doc` files(which include **header**, **footer** and a few **paragraphs**), following script is used, which use `HWPFDocument`.

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);

 POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
 HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

 Range range = doc.getRange();
 CharacterRun run = range.insertAfter("FROM SEHWAGGG A FOUUURRRRRR");
 run.setBold(true);
 run.setItalic(true);
```

The script works fine with normal documents which does not have **header** and **footer**. But seems that the issue appears with complex documents. It insert text, but in between the **paragraphs** (and at the beginning using `insertBefore()`). There are no text replacements required, just have to put the text at the end of the document. I searched similar scripts but  most of them handle text replacement.

How can I add the text at the end, after all paragraphs?

Comment: hmm..okay, Actually the documents I work with include header and footer and have 4 or 5 pages.  Let me check with different documents.

Comment: I'm not totaly sure if I got your question right. This is the document before: http://imgur.com/FH9SVkx
And this is the modification your code applies: http://imgur.com/Nt7XroL
Is it what you expected?

Comment: You are right, but the problem appears with complex documents having header, footer and a few paragraphs. A way to identify the end of the document is needed in this case, then insert the text.

Answer (score 1):

**I've tested It with the following document:**

[image]

**At first (with your original code) it completely destroyed the document:**

[image]

**By changing the following line, the insert works fine for me:**

```
// Old
Range range = doc.getEndnoteRange();
// New
Range range = doc.getEndnoteRange();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are out of luck with HWPF with the current state of the project.

I created a custom HWPF library for one of our clients, but the changes are not public. The changes were huge, so you can't spend - say - a week and assume that things will be fixed. You might get away with the current public HWPF when only some text needs to be replaced without changing the string length (`"abc" -> "123"` or `"a   " -> "1234"`).